# Match_parent on dynamically added GridLayout

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have some TextView inside a `GridLayout`. The `GridLayout` is inflated dynamically at runtime and then added to the main layout. The width of my boxitem (the GridLayout) is scaled correctly but the height seems to always wrap the content. I want the height do match the parent.

main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/CenterLayout"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
  <stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

BoxItem.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="10px">
    <TextView
        android:text="test: "
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:textColor="#009900"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="testy Mctestface"
        android:id="@+id/Shelf"
        android:textColor="#009900"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</GridLayout>
```

and here is my On Create

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BoxItem, null);
    FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.CenterLayout).AddView(view);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BoxItem, content_view,false)` instead of `LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BoxItem, null)` ? I don't know about xamarin but in java it can be done like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `LayoutParameters` rule to your BoxItem.axml when the view is found, for example:

```
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BoxItem, null);
view.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.CenterLayout).AddView(view);
```

This will solve the problem of layout parameters when dynamically add views.